# Why can't I pass a direct reference to a dictionary value to a function?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, parameters

Earlier today I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853483/can-i-pass-dictionary-values-entry-and-keys-to-function)
about passing dictionary values to a function.  While I understand now how to accomplish what I was trying to accomplish the why question (which was not asked) was never answered.  So my follow up is why can't I

```
def myFunction(newDict['bubba']):
    some code to process the parameter
```

Is it simply because the parser rules do not allow this?  I Googled for +Python +function +"allowable parameters" and did not find anything useful so I would appreciate any information.

I am oversimplifying what is going on.  I have a dictionary that is structured like

```
myDict={outerkey1:(innerkey1:value,innerkey2:value,. . .innerkeyn:value),outerkey2:(innerkey1:value,innerkey2:value,. . .innerkeyn:value),. . .}
```

As I said, I know how to do what I wanted-I got a very helpful answer.  But I started wondering why

```
 def myFunction(outerkey,myDict[outerkey]):
```

gives a syntax error which finely it occurred to me that it has to be a parsing problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the parser will reject this code.

Parameter lists are used in function definitions to bind identifiers within the function to arguments that are passed in from the outside **on invocation**.

Since `newDict['bubba']` is not a valid identifier, this doesn't make any sense -- you need to provide it as an invocation argument instead of a function parameter, since function parameters can only be identifiers.

Because you seem interested in the [formal grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html), here are the relevant parts:

```
funcdef ::= 
             [decorators] "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")"
              ":" suite

parameter_list ::= 
                 (defparameter ",")*
                (~~"*" identifier [, "**" identifier]
                 | "**" identifier
                 | defparameter [","] )

defparameter ::= 
             parameter ["=" expression]

identifier ::= 
             (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
```

In fact, the construct you are trying to use as an identifier is a subscription:

```
subscription ::= 
             primary "[" expression_list "]"
```

Comment: newDict['bubba'] is not a valid identifier I guess learning how to read the grammar will help with understanding that.  When I started down this line I decided it should work because when the function is called newDict['bubba'] references the thing I wanted the function to act on.     The solution was to use ** in front of the reference in the call and to use ** in front of a name in the definition as others have described but I didn't understand (and now do only at a superficial level) until your answer.  Hopefully when I get bored and read the grammar I will learn more thanks again

Comment: In Python, identifiers (names for objects) can only have letters, numbers, and underscores in them. If the grammar were to allow `newDict['bubba']` as a symbol that names an object, it would have trouble telling the difference between symbols that name objects and the subscript operation on lists/dictionaries. Plus, if you could use `newDict['bubba']` as an identifier, it'd be confusing, because `newDict` isn't a valid identifier, even though it looks like it's something you could index into.

Comment: dentifiers (names for objects) can only have letters, numbers, and underscores in them so this was really the crux of my problem today

Comment: Yep! In an effort to increase readability, Python allows a very limited set of characters in its identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be confused between the *definition* of a function and *calling* that function. As a simple example:

```
def f(x):
    y = x * x
    print "x squared is", y
```

By itself, this function doesn't do anything (ie. it doesn't print anything). If you put this in a source file and run it, nothing will be output. But then if you add:

```
f(5)
```

you will get the output "x squared is 25". When Python encounters the name of the function followed by *actual* parameters, it substitutes the value(s) of those actual parameters for the *formal* parameter(s) in the function definition. In this case, the formal parameter is called `x`. Then Python runs the function `f` with the value of `x` as 5. Now, the big benefit is you can use the same function again with a different value:

```
f(10)
```

prints "x squared is 100".

I hope I've understood the source of your difficulty correctly.

Comment: No I think I understand the difference I wanted to define my function and then later 
for key in myDict:
    result=myFunction(outerKey,myDict[innerKey])
As I said I got a good answer I wanted to know why my original approach did not work

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass references to objects.

```
a = { 'a' : 123, 'b' : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

def f(dictionary_value):
    dictionary_value.append(4)

f( a['b'] )
```

Does what you expect.  Dictionary element `a['b']` is passed "by reference" to the function `f` which updates the dictionary element.

Comment: This is interesting and looks simpler than the solution I worked with today and it works.    Cool So Can I have two accepted answers?

Comment: He is passing a *reference type* (a list). If you were to pass a['a'] in this way, performing dictionary_value += 2 would not affect a['a']. It's important to understand the difference between value and reference types!

Comment: Everything's a reference.  There is no useful distinction between "reference types" and "value types".  However, some types are immutable.  The immutability makes them look like 'value' types in Java or C++.

Comment: Right, but then you have to start explaining identifier binding -- I assume most people come from languages where ideas of "by value" and "by reference" will just click in their mind the right way. I should probably stop doing that. :-)

Comment: I am coming from SAS learned on the mainframe-what are those :)

Comment: Data step programming in SAS only has "by value" -- i.e. if you do "x = y;" then x will have a copy of the value of y.  You could kind-of get reference semantics in SAS using macro variables: If you do "%let y = 3; %let x = y;" then "%put(&&x.);" should display "3".  And later, "%let y = 7;", "%put(&&x.);" should then display "7".  So x is acting something like a "pointer" to y.  But really, it's a concept that doesn't exist in SAS to any meaningful degree.

Comment: Since this is a Python question, SAS features don't really apply very well.  Neither to C, C++ or Java features.  This question and the related question are fundamental confusion over the essential simplicity and transparency of Python variables.